# function php with PDO while loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone explain why this function does not work!

my SQL table - categories

```
id| name    | lft| rgt
----------------------
1 | Datorer  | 0 | 16
5 | test     | 4 | 6
4 | Sationär | 2 | 4
3 | Bärbar   | 1 | 3
2 | typ      | 3 | 15
```

conn.php - this is where i get the DB connection.

```
<?php
$db_host = "***********";
$db_username = *******";
$db_pass = "******";
$db_name = "*******";
$options  = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass, $options);
?>
```

functions.php - Here is my function, I can not figure out what's wrong!

```
function getSELECT($select,$table,$value) {
    include "conn.php"; // The database connection
    $sql = "SELECT '$select' FROM '$table' ORDER BY '$value'";
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!isset($r)) {
        trigger_error('PDO generic ERROR: No pdo query found', E_USER_ERROR);
    }else{
        return $r;
    }
}
```

test.php - Here I call on my function and run a while loop. But I do not get any names from the table categories.

```
include "conn.php";
include "functions.php";

$result = getSELECTall("categories","asc");
while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Your function name is getSELECT but you call it with getSELECTall

Comment: Function name and number of parameters are incorrect.

Comment: you are using quotes for col names in order clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use this function - it's insecure and makes no sense.

Instead, you have to learn basic SQL syntax and **always** strictly follow it.

Until you make yourself familiar with SQL and PDO, try to avoid writing functions at all. PDO itself is almost as good as any function you may devise.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC");
```

is all you need.

After all, it is WAY more readable and it **works** the way you expect, while your function doesn't.

Comment: okay so this is preferable?:
$result = $db->query("SELECT * from categories ORDER BY asc);
while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "Name: ".$row['name']."</br>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Table name and column name should be quoted within  " ` " (grave accent) and **not** with " ' ".
Try changing that